# ViewsLifeTime is not updating instantly?

Tags: list, timer-jobs, custom-timer-job, soap, popularity-trends

I got a counter to show how many visitors visit the page in my site. Users are visiting the website , but there is no change on the counter. It is the same like no one clicked it. Has it got a timer job? and what is the default frequency?  Or how can change the value of counter instantly?

Answer (score 0):

It is actually two timer jobs: A timer job to create the analytics and a timer job to import these analytics to the event store.

The first timer job is called "Analytics Timer Job for Search Service Application" and it is set to whatever schedule you set it to.
The second timer job is called "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Import" and on default runs in a 10 minute interval.

Once these two timer jobs execute your analytics events can be found within search. Bear in mind that there is also Tail Trimming, if there are less than 3 events, they are not tracked or visible.